# See output command terminal history in zsh terminal

Tags: linux, command-line, mac, terminal, zsh

I'm in an edge situation and I really need to retrieve some generate random value I executed last week in iTerm through the command: `cat /dev/urandom |LC_ALL=C tr -dc 'A-Z9' | fold -w 81 | head -n 1`

I used this command to create a seed for a new wallet for my virtual coins, I thought I copy it somewhere but I didn't...  I can't scroll up to look at this because I reach the maximum buffer limit so... So I was thinking its really possible at this point to recover this value? Some kind of history storing somewhere? Its almost a matter of life or death. I'm using iTerm zsh with MacOS Sierra.

Regards!

Comment: You can try increasing the limit, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12459755/zsh-iterm2-increase-number-of-lines-history). However, I'm not sure if it can be done postliminary.

Comment: Yeah, that's it, only take effects in the very moment it applies...

Comment: You can check if the `.zsh_history` file has more lines than the buffer. Maybe not since the previous cahnge didn't work.

Comment: Pretty useful! But not the output of the command results :(